# Calling controller method from linking function click handler does not update view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

My problem is the following: I have a directive with an isolated scope, where I want to bind a "click" callback to the element. Long story short, I want to do something similar to this:

```
...
<div test value='name' call='reset()'></div>
...

app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        template: '<button>{{value}}</button>', 
        scope: { 
            value: '=', 
            call: '&' 
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.bind('click', function(){
                scope.call();
            })
        }
    }
});

var myCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'John';

    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.name = "Some random name";
        console.log('reset name!');
    };
}
```

Alas, this does not work - it fires the `reset()` function, but controller's scope does not change (`$scope.name` remains the same). However, if I do binding in template:

```
template: '<button ng-click="call()">{{value}}</button>'
```

everything works fine. The problem is that in real task I do not use the template option, so I would like to ask if there is a way to do this binding inside the linking function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the click handler that you set up in your directive runs, it runs "outside" of Angular.  `$scope.name` is actually getting set (log it to see), but your view is not updating because Angular doesn't know about the change.  Add `scope.$apply()` to your click handler to cause Angular to enter a [digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime), and your view will update.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
   elem.bind('click', function(){
      scope.call();
      scope.$apply();
   })
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uMP9/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div test value='name' ng-click="call()"></div>
```

without directive.

If you want to keep Angular style you should /* *not use* */  use custom binding as less as possible